# Is it possible to copy text inside a book mark of a docx using DocumentFormat.OpenXML c# to new document with f=same format?

Tags: c#, openxml, new-operator, docx, bookmarks

We are trying to merge and split multiple docx files to one single document and then trying to split that single document to multiple documents.

we have tried with reading paragraphs and reading bookmarks seems promising.

using below code

```
 (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fbookMark, false))
            {
                foreach (BookmarkStart bookmark in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(bookmark.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(bookmark.Parent.InnerText);
                }
            }
```

output reads the book marks and inner text, when we try to copy this to a new document it fails. Is there a way to copy this bookmarked text to a new document, keeping the format and bookmark as is?